# Laravel 8 Model function to get field name

Tags: laravel

In my project I have many tables but one table is as bellow

```
user (id,name,active)
```

in my order controller I got ids of users in array and I want to get name so I have two ways

```
1. Loop through array and query each id with user table to get name
```

or
2. define one function in user model and get name of each id without doing 100s of query.

I try bellow but its not working

```
 public function getNameAttribute() 
    {
        return $this->name; 
    }
```

and from my controller I try these

```
User::name('2');
```

where 2 is id
I am getting error.

I need it in model because I will loop through each Id for some work and same time I will save name in different table.

what is best way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why have you written an accessor… to get the value of an attribute with the exact same name? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply using

```
User::whereIn('id', $listOfIds)->pluck('name');
```

You can read more about [pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) and [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) in Laravel documentation

Comment: I need in modal because when I loop through each Id for different work I can keep on saving in other table name

Comment: @Prodiger has given you the answer that is suitable to your question, consider refactoring/editing it, if you have missed some details